# Match [word] but not [word]apostrophe Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

my regex is dynamically constructed by using this code in javscript :

```
var regExp = new RegExp("\\b" + $("#value").val() + "\\b", "ig");
```

i.e the regex would be a simple `\bbrother\b/ig` and the problem is that it is also matching words such as

```
don in don't
sister in sister's
```

it should match word only if it is a whole word i.e

```
The don came late   - match
don't do that       - no match
she is my sister    - match
my sister's wedding - no match
```

**EDIT**: Thanks for the answers.Please suggest the fastest (or least expensive) method(if this makes an impact) if the regex is very large like `\bbrother|sister|car|truck.......\b` to the tune of 6500 OR words.

Comment: Do you want to not match words with quotation marks or do you want it to match the whole string including the quotation mark? So it will match `don't`, for instance?

Comment: Oh, your edit changes my answer a bit.  Give me a moment.  EDIT: Cancel that, I was thinking of a different performance issue.  My answer should be OK for what you're doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few ways you can do it.  I would recommend a forward negative lookahead.

`\bbrother\b(?!')`

The construct `(?!something)` ensures that `something` does not follow the match.